# sendMessage in functional style

Tags: functional-programming

Suppose I have 2 messenger objects that can send and receive messages. When message is received it is appended to some file:

```
class Messenger:
    def sendMessage(anotherMessenger, message):
        anotherMessenger.receiveMessage(message)


    def receiveMessage(msg):
        # appending msg to file



a = Messenger()
b = Messenger()

a.sendMessage(b, "Hello b!")
b.sendMessage(a, "Hi a!")
```

What would be a functional programming equivalent of the program above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FP your 'objects' tend to be functions.  In this case, instead of multiple objects, each with two member functions you would have multiple functions to handle different scenarios.

In this case you have:

```
receiveMessage: string -> ()
```

That is, `receiveMessage` is a function that takes a `string` and returns nothing - `unit`. Likewise:

```
sendMessage: (f: string -> ()) -> (msg: string) -> ()
```

I.e. `sendMessage` takes a `receiveMessage` implementation and a `string` and returns `unit`.

So, using a language like F# we can have the following:

```
let sendMessage (f: string -> ()) (msg: string) = f(msg)

let aRecv (msg: string) = // Do something with msg
let bRecv (msg: string) = // Do something else with msg

...

sendMessage bRecv "Hello b!"
sendMessage aRecv "Hi a!"
...
```

Since your question is kind of generic I will leave this as a kind of generic answer.  If you have something more specific in mind this answer can be expanded on.